# Deserialization problem with DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, wcf, json, dictionary, serialization

I've got the following piece of JSON:

```
[{
    "name": "numToRetrieve",
    "value": "3",
    "label": "Number of items to retrieve:",
    "items": {
        "1": "1",
        "3": "3",
        "5": "5"
    },
    "rules": {
        "range": "1-2"
    }
},
{
    "name": "showFoo",
    "value": "on",
    "label": "Show foo?"
},
{
    "name": "title",
    "value": "Foo",
    "label": "Foo:"
}]
```

All in one line version (suitable for a string literal):

```
[{\"name\":\"numToRetrieve\",\"value\":\"3\",\"label\":\"Number of items to retrieve:\",\"items\":{\"1\":\"1\",\"3\":\"3\",\"5\":\"5\"},\"rules\":{\"range\":\"1-2\"}},{\"name\":\"showFoo\",\"value\":\"on\",\"label\":\"Show foo?\"},{\"name\":\"title\",\"value\":\"Foo\",\"label\":\"Foo:\"}]
```

In the above example, `name`, `value`, and `label` are required but `items` and `rules` are optional.

Here's the class I'm trying to deserialize into:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace foofoo
{
    [DataContract]
    public sealed class FooDef
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "name", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "value", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "label", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Label { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "items", IsRequired = false)]
        public Dictionary<string, string> Items { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "rules", IsRequired = false)]
        public Dictionary<string, string> Rules { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's the code I use to deserialize:

```
var json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<FooDef>));
var bar = "[{\"name\":\"numToRetrieve\",\"value\":\"3\",\"label\":\"Number of items to retrieve:\",\"items\":{\"1\":\"1\",\"3\":\"3\",\"5\":\"5\"},\"rules\":{\"range\":\"1-2\"}},{\"name\":\"showFoo\",\"value\":\"on\",\"label\":\"Show foo?\"},{\"name\":\"title\",\"value\":\"Foo\",\"label\":\"Foo:\"}]";
var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bar));
var foo = json.ReadObject(stream);
stream.Close();
```

Everything goes reasonably well except that `items` and `rules` are empty for the first `FooDef` pass. I have tried everything under the sun to try and get them populated: custom classes, `NameValueCollection`, `KeyValuePair<string, string>`, `List` of both of the latter, and every other collection that seemed to apply. [EDIT: I forgot to try `Hashtable`, which seemed like an obvious candidate. Didn't work.]

The problem, as I see it, is that the key piece under `items` and `rules` is open-ended. That is, it's not always going to be called `range` or `3`. Any advice or ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

IMHO there is no way to deserialize the JSON string you provided into a .NET class using DataContractJsonSerializer.

The problem comes from the way [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412168.aspx) serializes dictionaries. You could use an alternative serializer such as [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) (which I strongly recommend) or [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) (I think it was deprecated in favor of DataContractJsonSerializer but it will work for your scenario).

You can also read [these](http://blog.geocortex.com/2009/02/17/handy-trick-for-json-serialization/) [rants](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2008/01/07/wcf-json-serialization-is-flawed/).

Documentation: **[Serializing Collections - Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm)**

Comment: That's kind of what I feared. I was avoiding switching over to JavaScriptSerializer because of the deprecation, but I'm glad to hear that it was undeprecated in 3.5 SP1. I'll try it using that class.

Comment: I tried it with JavaScriptSerializer and it worked perfectly. I ended up using Dictionary<string, string> but Hashtable worked also.

Answer (score 7):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/071f73bb-e141-4a68-ae61-05635382934f

Check this article out - it solved my problem almost perfectly. I had to change their object[] Type to a string, but i'm only using strings:string type Key/Value pairs, so no problems there.