# Getting friendlist facebook..but json response is not desired one

Tags: android, facebook

I know its not a different question. But I tried to look every link available. But didn't find answer to my question. Here is my code:

```
            private void getFriends(){
            String fqlQuery = "SELECT uid,name,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN " +
                    "(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";

            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

            Request request = new Request(session,
                    "/fql",                         
                    params,                         
                    HttpMethod.GET,                 
                    new Request.Callback(){       
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    Log.i("result", "Result: " + response.toString());
                           }
```

Json respnse is:

```
06-29 12:20:15.542: I/result(392): Result: {Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 104, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An access token is required to request this resource.}, isFromCache:false}
```

Comment: It doesn't see an access code-  you didn't add the login info.

Comment: visit **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340271/facebook-graph-api-retrieve-friends-with-json-and-c-sharp)** this should help you with what you need

Comment: So what should I do in this case??

Comment: make sure your user is logged in

Comment: I added a session..how to add more info..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way:
    private class FetchUserPhotos extends AsyncTask {

```
    private ProgressDialog pd = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(AndroidFacebookConnectActivity.this, "WWD",
                "Fetching photos..", true, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Request request = new Request(facebook.getSession(), "/me/friends");

        Response response = request.executeAndWait();
        String resp = response.toString();
        return resp;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        pd.dismiss();
    }

}
```