# How to parse JSON and iterate over it?

Tags: c#, .net, json, iteration

How can I iterate over the `images` in JSON of following format? Length of `images` collection can be arbitrary. Can I manipulate it to make it a list, or what options do I have to parse this?

```
images: {
  0: {
    filename: "image1.jpg"
  },
  1: {
    filename: "image2.jpg"
  },
  2: {
    filename: "image3.jpg"
  },
}
```

Comment: Your json seems odd. Shouldn't images be an array instead of an object?

Comment: yes, the data returned is really wierd, sometimes it is returned as an array, but sometimes its not, I'm working on the logic for when its not

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to create a `dynamic` representation of your json:

```
dynamic jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(@"{
    images: {
        0: {
            filename: ""image1.jpg""
        },
        1: {
            filename: ""image2.jpg""
        },
        2: {
            filename: ""image3.jpg""
        }
    }
    }");


foreach(var item in jsonData["images"])
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a read of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596271/deserialization-problem-with-datacontractjsonserializer), you'll notice that [`JSON.NET`](http://james.newtonking.com/json) is a recommended library to use for situations like this.

You could try using the [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create objects from JSON input, but when I tried it just now, I couldn't get it to work with a collection of items in the JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this with vanilla javascript like this:**

```
for (objectName in data["images"]) {
    html += data["images"][objectName]["filename"] + "<br />"
}
```

**Full HTML file example below**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="result"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var data = {
                "images": {
                    "0": {
                        "filename": "image1.jpg"
                    },
                    "1": {
                        "filename": "image2.jpg"
                    },
                    "2": {
                        "filename": "image3.jpg"
                    }
                }};

            var html = '';
            for (objectName in data["images"]) {
                html += data["images"][objectName]["filename"] + "<br />"
            }

            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html;

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring it out - although may not be best practice it worked in this case

```
var imageHoldingList = new List<VehicleImagesModel>();
var connectionResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(results);
var jImage = connectionResponse["response"]["vehicles"]["images"].Children();

foreach (var image in jImage)
{
   var h = new VehicleImagesModel
   {
      Filename = image.First.filename.ToString(),
      Caption = image.First.caption.ToString()
   };
   imageHoldingList.Add(h);
```

}